# I want to display Bangla language from my database

Tags: mysqli, utf-8

I want to display Bangla language from my database . but it shows error message

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\ban.php on line 362
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\ban.php on line 364

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.query.php). `mysqli::query` expects a single parameter, which is `$query` and `mysqli_query` expects two parameters: `$link` and `$query`. You passed a single parameter, presumably `$query` instead of passing `$link` and `$query`.

When you called `mysqli_fetch_array`, your code assumes that everything went smoothly, which is clearly not the case. Make sure you run `mysqli_query` in the proper manner and when you achieve that, you solved your main problem, which does not exclude other problems, off course.

Comment: I would like to know the problem with my answer so I can improve its quality, thanks!